# Google colab pro GPU running extremely slow

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am running a Convnet on colab Pro GPU. I have selected GPU in my runtime and can confirm that GPU is available. I am running exactly the same network as yesterday evening, but it is taking about 2 hours per epoch... last night it took about 3 minutes per epoch... nothing has changed at all. I have a feeling colab may have restricted my GPU usage but I can't work out how to tell if this is the issue. Does GPU speed fluctuate much depending on time of day etc? Here are some diagnostics which I have printed, does anyone know how I can investigate deeper what the root cause of this slow behaviour is?

I also tried changing to accelerator in colab to 'None', and my network was the same speed as with 'GPU' selected, implying that for some reason i am no longer training on GPU, or resources have been severely limited. I am using Tensorflow 2.1.

```
gpu_info = !nvidia-smi
gpu_info = '\n'.join(gpu_info)
if gpu_info.find('failed') >= 0:
  print('Select the Runtime → "Change runtime type" menu to enable a GPU accelerator, ')
  print('and then re-execute this cell.')
else:
  print(gpu_info)

Sun Mar 22 11:33:14 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64.00    Driver Version: 418.67       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P100-PCIE...  Off  | 00000000:00:04.0 Off |                    0 |
| N/A   40C    P0    32W / 250W |   8747MiB / 16280MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
def mem_report():
  print("CPU RAM Free: " + humanize.naturalsize( psutil.virtual_memory().available ))

  GPUs = GPUtil.getGPUs()
  for i, gpu in enumerate(GPUs):
    print('GPU {:d} ... Mem Free: {:.0f}MB / {:.0f}MB | Utilization {:3.0f}%'.format(i, gpu.memoryFree, gpu.memoryTotal, gpu.memoryUtil*100))

mem_report()
```

```
CPU RAM Free: 24.5 GB
GPU 0 ... Mem Free: 7533MB / 16280MB | Utilization  54%
```

Still no luck speeding things up, here is my code, maybe I have overlooked something... btw the images are from an old Kaggle competition, the data can be found here. The training images are saved on my google drive. https://www.kaggle.com/c/datasciencebowl

```
#loading images from kaggle api

#os.environ['KAGGLE_USERNAME'] = ""
#os.environ['KAGGLE_KEY'] = ""

#!kaggle competitions download -c datasciencebowl

#unpacking zip files

#zipfile.ZipFile('./sampleSubmission.csv.zip', 'r').extractall('./')
#zipfile.ZipFile('./test.zip', 'r').extractall('./')
#zipfile.ZipFile('./train.zip', 'r').extractall('./')

data_dir = pathlib.Path('train')

image_count = len(list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg')))
CLASS_NAMES = np.array([item.name for item in data_dir.glob('*') if item.name != "LICENSE.txt"])

shrimp_zoea = list(data_dir.glob('shrimp_zoea/*'))
for image_path in shrimp_zoea[:5]:
    display.display(Image.open(str(image_path)))
```

```
image_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                                                  validation_split=0.2)
                                                                  #rotation_range = 40,
                                                                  #width_shift_range = 0.2,
                                                                  #height_shift_range = 0.2,
                                                                  #shear_range = 0.2,
                                                                  #zoom_range = 0.2,
                                                                  #horizontal_flip = True,
                                                                  #fill_mode='nearest')
```

```
validation_split = 0.2
BATCH_SIZE = 32
BATCH_SIZE_VALID = 10
IMG_HEIGHT = 224
IMG_WIDTH = 224
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = np.ceil(image_count*(1-(validation_split))/BATCH_SIZE)
VALIDATION_STEPS = np.ceil((image_count*(validation_split)/BATCH_SIZE))
```

```
train_data_gen = image_generator.flow_from_directory(directory=str(data_dir),
                                                     subset='training',
                                                     batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                                     class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                     shuffle=True,
                                                     target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                     classes = list(CLASS_NAMES))

validation_data_gen = image_generator.flow_from_directory(directory=str(data_dir),
                                                     subset='validation',
                                                     batch_size=BATCH_SIZE_VALID,
                                                     class_mode = 'categorical',
                                                     shuffle=True,
                                                     target_size=(IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH),
                                                     classes = list(CLASS_NAMES))
```

```
model_basic = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1000, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(121, activation='softmax')
])

model_basic.summary()
```

```
model_basic.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
history = model_basic.fit(
          train_data_gen,
          epochs=10,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=validation_data_gen,
          steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
          validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS,
          initial_epoch=0         
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `nvidia-smi` output makes it clear that a GPU is connected. Where are you storing your training data? If not on the local disk, I'd recommend storing it there. The speed of remote transfers of training data may vary based on where your Colab backend is located.

Comment: The images are saved on my google drive, which my notebook is mounted to. I have added my code to add a bit more detail.

Comment: Try copying the images from your Google Drive to the local disk as the first step in your notebook. It's likely that Drive network rate limits are reducing the speed of your training loop.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that, just seems strange that there is such a drastic difference in training speed between yesterday and today, maybe I changed something and forgot about it I'm not sure, but getting a headache thinking about it now.

Comment: Sorry Bob, actually how do I load a directory onto my colab disk?

Answer (score 7):

In the end the bottle neck seems to be loading images from google drive to colab in each batch. Loading the images to disk reduced the time per epoch to about 30 seconds... here is the code I used to load to disk:

```
!mkdir train_local
!unzip train.zip -d train_local
```

After uploading my train.zip file to colab

Comment: Thank you! This increased my Training speed 3-5 fold!

Answer (score 0):

From [Colab's FAQ](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/faq.html#gpu-availability):

> The types of GPUs that are available in Colab vary over time. This is necessary for Colab to be able to provide access to these resources for free. The GPUs available in Colab often include Nvidia K80s, T4s, P4s and P100s. There is no way to choose what type of GPU you can connect to in Colab at any given time. Users who are interested in more reliable access to Colab’s fastest GPUs may be interested in [Colab Pro](http://colab.research.google.com/signup?utm_source=faq&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=what_types_of_gpus).

If the code did not change, the issue is likely related to performance characteristics of the GPU types you happened to be connected to.